# it must be a function, usually from React.PropTypes

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass string from Main to Header. It succeeds but warning. I'm a beginner of React so I can not figure out what `it must be a function` means.

Anyone knows how to solve this warning?

The warning is:

[image]

And my code is below:

*Main.js*

```
import React from 'react';

import Header from './Header';
import AppList from './AppList/AppList';
import Footer from './Footer';

const propTypes = {
  mainInfo: React.PropTypes.shape({
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    apps: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  }),
};

class Main extends React.Component {
  static methodsAreOk() {
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header title={this.props.mainInfo.title} />
        <AppList apps={this.props.mainInfo.apps} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Main.propTypes = propTypes;

export default Main;
```

*Header.js*

```
import React from 'react';

const propTypes = {
  title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequred,
};

class Header extends React.Component {
  static methodsAreOk() {
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Header.propTypes = propTypes;

export default Header;
```

Comment: If make `this.props.mainInfo.title` just a string, the warning is not changed.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You have an error: `React.PropTypes.string.isRequred`. Spell `isRequired` correctly, and it should be ok.

Comment: serious :facepalm: when I read this and it solved my problem.

Comment: You are a life savior! what a terrific catch!

Comment: yeah, you did a good job! `hideModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,` !== `hideModal: PropTypes.func.required,`

Comment: In my case I had written `PropTypes.boolean` instead of `PropTypes.bool`.

Comment: I had isRequired.isRequired U_U

Comment: ha....I too had this typo.  Couldn't figure out where this `func` stuff was coming from, awesome post!

Comment: I love StackOverflow. Spent 2 whole days seeing so much red debugging a JS codebase. The reason I love working in TS more these days.

Comment: I don't have a typo, and I still get this message.

Comment: In my case I had `PropTypes.Number` instead of `PropTypes.number`

Answer (score 42):

This happens when your PropType is actually `undefined`.

In my case I had specified a propType of `PropTypes.integer`, which is not one of the list of proptypes. That literally turns into `undefined`. Instead I should have used `PropTypes.number`.

Watch out for similar mistakes with `PropTypes.bool` vs `PropTypes.boolean`, as well as `PropTypes.func` vs `PropTypes.function`.

Comment: Arrgh! And I just did it with `PropTypes.boolean` instead of `PropTypes.bool`. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer, much more generic than the selected answer. Just did it with `boolean` instead of `bool` too :P

Comment: Even after reading this answer it still took me a long time to realize I had written `PropTypes.function` instead of `PropTypes.func`! 

Answer (score 9):

Also, it's `bool` for booleans. I skimmed the docs and had the exact same problem until I went back and read them carefully.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 4):

e.g.

```
React.PropTypes.sting
React.PropTypes.text
```

React could also tell the user: "The PropType 'sting' you defined is undefined. Did you misspell it?. Available PropTypes are: string, number, bool, etc."

Comment: I had boolean instead of `bool` to get this error :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case it happened when I declared `Component.propTypes` and below that, instead of writing `Component.defaultProps` I wrote again `Component.propTypes` assigning the default values.

Answer (score 2):

## just copy & paste, unless you can make sure that you would not type some typo!

> I also had this problem, and it wastes my much time to fix it!

So, just make a note!

### VS code & plugins

> in case a typo!

```jsx

```
TestModal.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    //badHideModal: PropTypes.func.required,
    hideModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

```

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem regarding function and boolean prop type it solved by replacing with func and bool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to solve the problem in 3 steps:

- **step 1:** install NPM prop-types package (`npm prop-types install`);
- **step 2:**
  import the package in your file.

**Code:** `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

- **step 3:** Remove the `React` keyword from the statement (e.g: `React.PropTypes.string.isRequired to PropTypes.string.isRequired` depends on your statement, so just remove the `React` keyword, because you are now importing from **prop-types**, not from the React library.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to `isRequred` instead of `isRequired` happened to me. I was *trying* to define the default props, but copy-pasted the propTypes and never changed the name, so I ended up with something like this:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Main = ({ title }) => // whatever

Main.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string
}

Main.propTypes = { // this should have been Main.defaultProps! ‍♂️
  title: 'This is the default title!'
}
```

So PropTypes was complaining about the `title`'s prop type not being the right thing. It said something like "it must be a function, usually from React.PropTypes but it was a string".

I thought I was going crazy. I was looking at the first `Main.propTypes` and trying to find typo or anything that could be wrong, but as you can see it was completely fine. I opened multiple files that had prop types defined but weren't throwing the error.

I was obviously looking at the wrong place but eventually found it out of luck. I was pretty lucky to actually find it. These facepalming bugs are quite hard to figure out because they're like a magician moving one hand to attract all the eyes while preparing the trick with the other one, usually in plain sight.